# Как анимировать линию диагоналей прямоугольника?

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation

Я пытаюсь добавить анимацию линий по диагонали.
 Я знаю высоту и ширину прямоугольника (динамически складывается).
   Теперь пытаюсь анимировать строку от `N` до `L`, или от `O` до `M`.

Попытался сделать это с SVG, - увеличить x1, y1, x2, y2 линии, но это становится сложным.

Есть любое более простое решение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

### SVG

Вы можете присвоить своим линиям `stroke-dashoffset` и анимировать его до 0. Чтобы рассчитать значения для `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`, я использовал метод - [getTotalLength()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength) для вычисления значений `stroke-dasharray` и `stroke-dashoffset`.

```css
svg{background:#efefef;width:100vh}
rect,line{stroke:black; fill:none}

#om{stroke-dasharray:94.34px;
stroke-dashoffset:94.34px;
animation: om 1s linear forwards;}


@keyframes om {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 100 70">  
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="50" />
  <line id="om" x1="90" y1="60" x2="10" y2="10" />
</svg>
```

И на этот раз обе строки анимированы с `M` на `O` и `L` на `N`: просто измените значения с `x1` на `x2` и наоборот. То же самое для `y`. Это изменит направление линии.

```css
svg{background:#efefef;width:100vh}
rect,line{stroke:black; fill:none}

#mo,#ln{stroke-dasharray:94.34px;
stroke-dashoffset:94.34px;
animation: om 1s linear forwards;}


@keyframes om {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 100 70">  
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="80" height="50" />
  
  <line id="mo" x2="90" y2="60" x1="10" y1="10" />
  <line id="ln" x2="90" y2="10" x1="10" y1="60" />
</svg>
```

Я использую одну и ту же анимацию для #om и #nl

Answer (score 3):

- Вот простая идея с `background` окраской.

  Вам просто нужно увеличить `background-size`, чтобы нарисовать линии:

*Анимация при наведении курсора*

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  background:
    /*M - O*/
    linear-gradient(to top right,
      transparent calc(50% - 3px),red calc(50% - 2px),
      red calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 3px)) top left,
      
    /*N - L*/  
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,
      transparent calc(50% - 3px),#000 calc(50% - 2px),
      #000 calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 3px)) bottom left;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:0 0;
  transition:1s linear;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

- Измените `background-position`, чтобы изменить начало анимации:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  background:
    /*M - O*/
    linear-gradient(to top right,
      transparent calc(50% - 3px),red calc(50% - 2px),
      red calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 3px)) bottom right,
      
    /*N - L*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,
      transparent calc(50% - 3px),#000 calc(50% - 2px),
      #000 calc(50% + 2px),transparent calc(50% + 3px)) top right;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:0 0;
  transition:1s linear;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

- Вот версия без использования `calc()`, которая будет работать с IE.
  Найти правильные значения будет немного сложно, и вам понадобится
  анимация `background-position`, которая также сложна:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  background:
    /*M - O*/
    linear-gradient(to top right,
      transparent 176px,red 176px,
      red 181px,transparent 181px) left 200% top 200%,
      
    /*N - L*/
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,
      transparent 176px,black 176px,
      black 181px,transparent 181px) left -100% bottom -100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:200% 200%;
  transition:1s linear;
}
.box:hover {
  background-position:0 0,left 0 bottom 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```